# Embed form (has many) with activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, formtastic

I am making a blog using rails and activeadmin. I associate tags to each post. I want to know how to configure activeadmin to add tags on posts.

I want to be able to create tags from a new Post form. How can i do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

if `Posts` has_many `Tags` then something like this could work.

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs do
    f.input :title
    f.input :content
    f.has_many :tags do |fu|
      fu.input :name
      fu.input :_destroy, :as=>:boolean, :required => false, :label => 'Delete Tag' unless fu.object.new_record?
    end
  end
end
```

ActiveAdmin expects that the `Post` model `accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags`

like..

```
class Post
  #....
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags
end
```